Difference between graphConv and GCNConv
Can anyone tell me what is the difference between GraphConv and GCNConv? Or can anyone shows me a tutorial about them? I found the formulas in PyTorch Geometric website but I can not find any explanation about them. I see some people mention GraphConv has better result rather than GCNConv and I applied each of them in my GNN model and found yes using GraphConv has better result than GCNConv but I can not understand why this happen? I appreciate if anyone can guid me to understand the difference between them.

From what I understood the key difference is the K-hop neighborhood-based approach used in GraphConv for aggregation. The multiple hops are quite helpful for gathering information from distant neighboring nodes. This is why GraphConv generally performs better than GCNConv. Check the tutorial below from pytorch_geometric document:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1I8a0DfQ3fI7Njc62__mVXUlcAleUclnb?usp=sharing

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
